# How do I resolve java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.dataflow.model.Environment.setSdkPipelineOptions with Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I copied the [MinimalWordCount](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/MinimalWordCount.java) example.

I also copied all the dependencies from `pom.xml`. When I run it with

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.example.MyExample
```

it compiles, but I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.dataflow.model.Environment.setSdkPipelineOptions` with the stacktrace pointing to the `p.run()` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the dependencies, you need to add the Google Cloud Dataflow parent pom.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.google.cloud.dataflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-cloud-dataflow-java-sdk-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: This is a very good point. These are code examples, but not project configuration examples. It is quite reasonable (expected) that you would want to choose your own parent pom. I've filed [BEAM-442](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-442) to track it for Beam and [DataflowJavaSDK-examples#6](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/issues/6) for the Dataflow SDK.